# System of equations from coefficients of series

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion

I have two functions $F_1(a,b,x)$ and $F_2(a,b,x)$ I expand these functions about the point $x=0$

```
  Series[F1,{x,0,2}]
  Series[F2,{x,0,2}]
```

the coefficients are depended on $a$ and $b$ variables. I want to create the system of equations where all coefficients are equal to zero.

$$F_1(a,b,x)=A_0(a,b)+A_1(a,b)x+A_2(a,b)x^2$$
$$F_2(a,b,x)=B_0(a,b)+B_1(a,b)x+B_2(a,b)x^2$$

so the system of the equations is

$A_0(a,b)=0, \ A_1(a,b)=0, \ A_2(a,b)=0, B_0(a,b)=0, \ B_1(a,b)=0, \ B_2(a,b)=0$

I know that `CoefficientList[Series[F1,{x,0,2}],{x}]` returns coefficients of the expansion, but how can I use them to create equations? And how can I pass them to `Solve[]` function?

Comment: `Solve[Thread[coeffs == 0], (* stuff *)]`. Your system is currently overdetermined, however.

Comment: J.M. thank you very much. I think your comment is the answer to my question.

Comment: If you think you understand what `Thread[]` did to solve your problem, I would suggest writing an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested J.M. above I use `Thread[]` function which converts list to list of equations, for example `Thread[{a,b,c}==0]`  =  `{a=0,b=0,c=0}`. So I have two lists

```
coeff1 = CoefficientList[Series[F1,{x,0,2}],{x}]
coeff2 = CoefficientList[Series[F1,{x,0,2}],{x}]
```

I join them using `Join[]` function

```
coeffs = Join[coeff1,coeff2];
```

and then I solve the system of equations

```
 Solve[Thread[coeffs == 0], {a,b}]
```